# How to append items to a list while testing that item against list with if conditions

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I am adding randomly generated points to a list if it is contained within a specified polygon until I have the number of points I require:

```
def random_points_in_polygon(number, polygon):
    points = []
    min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = polygon.bounds
    i= 0
    while i < number:
        point = Point(np.random.uniform(min_x, max_x), np.random.uniform(min_y, max_y))
        if polygon.contains(point):
            points.append(point)
            i += 1
    return points  # returns list of shapely point

# generate determined points within field polygon
points = random_points_in_polygon(pointscount, gdf.iloc[0].geometry)
```

I would however like to add another if condition testing each new point continually against each point previously added to the list.

I would essentially need to add a distance test to test a minimum distance of each point against the points already added to the list via something like:

```
for j in range(len(points)):
    distancetest = j.distance(point)
    if distancetest > 60:
       if polygon.contains(point)
            points.append(point)
            i += 1
```

If a newly generated point is over a certain distance from each of the previous points already added and it is contained within the polygon the point will be added to the list. I find myself getting stuck in an infinite loop attempting to add this additional condition in my current code. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you share the complete code? What is your final code after integrating the second condition?

Comment: Use the `all()` function with a generator that tests the distance against each element.

Comment: `all(j.distance(point) > 60 for j in points)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not testing all the points, you're adding to `points` for each point that it's more than 60 units away from (except that `j` isn't actually a `Point`, it's the index in the list).

Use the `all()` function to test if it's more than 60 from all the existing elements of `points`.

```
    while i < number:
        point = Point(np.random.uniform(min_x, max_x), np.random.uniform(min_y, max_y))
        if polygon.contains(point) and all(p.distance(point) > 60 for p in points):
            points.append(point)
            i += 1
```